# How to download pdf in salesforce mobile app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app

Hi We have requirement to View and download pdf in Salesforce1 Community Mobile App. any suggestions on it if download possible?

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IKOMQA4

Comment: I went through that already. but looking for example